# View Artwork in Sidebar - iTunes 11

Tags: itunes, macos, album-art, sidebar

How can I view the artwork in the sidebar in the latest version of iTunes 11 ?

Comment: I haven't figured this out - but I do know my favorite player tool, [Take Five](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/take-five/id424437399?mt=12) works well with both versions 10 and 11 of iTunes and will show artwork briefly as tracks change. It's a fairly small artwork browser, but easily twice the size of iTunes 11's thumbnails.

Comment: I'm using itunification to show artwork and song title as I change through songs. But I do like to see the artwork in the sidebar just like before :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is no longer a function (even hidden) in the new iTunes. To me, this looks like another useful feature got dropped. The closest thing I've found so far is clicking the cover in the top display pops out a resizable window (a-la coversutra). Sorry mate.

Comment: Is there a plugin or something ?